# Foundation reveal-modal: how can I return to parent modal after closing modal-in-a-modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

Here is an example of modal in a modal.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

Is there any way to return to the first modal in the same state, after closing child one?
Or, even better, how can I get modal over modal, not replace first modal with second?

**Update:** OK, I can just open first modal again, state is the same.

```
$('#parent-dialog').foundation('reveal','open');
```

Is it possible to make modal-over-modal?

Comment: Same issue here! Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

> You can create a reveal modal with another inside it. Setting
>   `reveal.multiple_opened` to `true` will not close previously opened reveal
>   modals. You can even put a video into a reveal.

Source: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html